# How to place adView below?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I create a game which has a custom view derived from surfaceView. and in the game I want to place adView below the gameView. but the problem is , if I place adView below the gameView , the adView wont show up.. I do all the layouting in the code because its easier to maintain..

here is the code..

If i place the adView above the gameView it will show up

```
private RelativeLayout layout;   //the gameView container
private LinearLayout mainLayout;  //the main layout
private RocketView rocketView;   //the gameView
private AdView adView;             //the adView
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d9e9ea3740e8");
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        mainLayout.addView(adView);   // -->> here i place the adView first

        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        mainLayout.addView(layout);   //--->> then i place the gameView later

        rocketView = new RocketView(this);
        layout.addView(rocketView);
        setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

But if i place the adView below it won't show up.

```
private RelativeLayout layout;
private LinearLayout mainLayout;
private RocketView rocketView;
private Launcher launcher;

private AdView adView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        mainLayout.addView(layout);

        rocketView = new RocketView(this);
        layout.addView(rocketView);

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d9e9ea3740e8");
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        mainLayout.addView(adView);
        setContentView(mainLayout);

}
```

I think I know what happen.. 
after adView loading the adRequest and get the ads, its not streching above, but it streching below, so it not showing in the screen. but I don't know how to solve this problem. please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no need for your linear layout, mainLayout. Add both rocketView and adView to your relativelayout, layout. Give adView the attributes align_parent_bottom, wrap_content (height) and wrap_content or fill_parent for width. Then give rocketView fill_parent for width and height and have it be "above" adView.

Comment: And don't forget to change the parameter of setContentView() when your done.

Comment: how to give the attribute to adView?

Comment: and anyway , if I dont use the linear layout , the ad would block some of the view. thats why i use another layout outside

Comment: RelativeLayout will also keep the layouts from overlapping. Especially in your case, you should be doing the layout in XML. It makes it very easy to gives layouts and elements attributes. If you were to do all your layout in Java, you have to make new LayoutParams objects and call setLayoutParams() on everything. Believe me, this gets messy :)

Comment: If you'd like I could post some example XML?

Comment: This is a great resource from the Android developers website that you may find useful: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: no please . as I said before..
the custom view (gameView) is what keeps me from using XML layout. I don't know how to configure all the param in XML. :(

Comment: I know how to use XML layout. and other than this activity, I use the XML layout. but for this one is special case.

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't know how to do with your gameview in XML? Because, from what you said, I'm sure XML would be a good (if not the best) approach, but if you insist on doing it in Java, do as I said in the 4th comment. Create a new LayoutParams object then manipulate that how you need to before assigning it to your view with setLayoutParams(). RelativeLayout.LayoutParams seems to be the most flexible and is probably exactly what you want.

Comment: well.. found some about LayoutParam. but still , the ads won't show if placed below. I think i would give up and just put it above . hehe. *still lot of another things to do here* . thank you! :)